# The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated

Tags: wcf, autofac

Within my XXXX.WS WCF services project I'm trying to get DI/IOC using autofac going...been at it all day but I think I'm close (different errors are progress here)...this error I can't understand how to shake..."AutofacServieHost.Container static property must be set..."..but I think I am setting it!?! What am I doing wrong?

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new DatabaseFactory()).As<IDatabaseFactory>().Named<DatabaseFactory>("DBFactory");
        builder.Register(c => new ListingSqlRepository(c.ResolveNamed<DatabaseFactory>("DBFactory"))).As<IListingSqlRepository>().Named<ListingSqlRepository>("LSR");
        builder.Register(c => new ListingRepository(c.ResolveNamed<ListingSqlRepository>("LSR"))).As<IListingRepository>().Named<ListingRepository>("LR");
        builder.Register(c => new Service1(c.ResolveNamed<IListingRepository>("LR"))).As<IService1>();

        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:57924/Service1");
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), address);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), string.Empty);

            host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IService1>(container);

            //BREAKS HERE?
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl = address });
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The host has been opened.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Then the SERVICE:
    namespace LOTW2012.WS
{

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private IListingRepository _listingRepository { get; set; }

    public Service1(IListingRepository iLR) {
        this._listingRepository = iLR;
    }

    public Service1()
    {
    }


    public List<Listing> GetListingsByStateName(string stateName)
    {   
        //todo ..getall for now
        var listings = _listingRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        return listings;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell the Autofac WCF integration about the container you build by setting the property in question:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// ...

AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();

// ...
```

This will allow Autofac to resolve service types.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for offering some help...Is the using not building the container? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Might you paste how you wire up DI/IOC in your WCF service? As I was following what was on the AutoFac site WCF page.

Comment: @Bryant: It looks as though you are using the example from the "Self-Hosting" section of that wiki article, but the fact that you are doing it in `Application_Start` hints that you are using a web site as the service's context. You might try the "Servers Hosted in IIS" section, which discusses the `AutofacHostFactory.Container` property.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but that too refers to Application_StartUp..do I not need a global in my WCF project to wire up DI/IOC? wasn't sure how my repository was going to be able to pull data with WireingUp autoFac in the WCF project itself?

Comment: @Bryant: What matters is where WCF runs: if it's self-hosted (not a web site), your original example is correct. If it runs within an ASP.NET web site, which has a `global.asax` and `Application_Start`, you need to set the `AutofacHostFactory.Container` property.