# microsoft grpc-for-wcf-developers-master code fails on IIS

Tags: wcf, github, iis, autofac

getting the [grpc-for-wcf-developers-master](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers), I tried to host the WCF service in the [tradersys](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/tree/master/PortfoliosSample/wcf/TraderSys) on IIS version 10 on Windows 10, which throws an exception:

[Error by IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpAI3.jpg)

The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I'm aware of this issue as discussed several times here, such as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9846372/13823060).
Yet the code by Microsft contains the appropriate autofac container.

the question is:

Is there any special settings on IIS for resolving this issue?
as I said earlier IISExpress just works fine.

seems the AppInitialize() method in which

```
AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
```

resides, doesn't invoke.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, I will check and let you know. though it is very surprising why Microsoft code throws an exception, I expected it to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I found that you need to integrate IOC with WCF, which needs to change your code.
**Here is my demo:**

[image]

This is my project directory.We need to add two classes: ManualProxy and CustomServiceHostFactory.

```
   public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost
              CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ManualProxy.TargetFactory = () => new PortfolioService(new PortfolioRepository());
            return base.CreateServiceHost(typeof(ManualProxy), baseAddresses);
        }
    }
```

This is the CustomServiceHostFactory class.

```
 public class ManualProxy : IPortfolioService
    {
        private readonly IPortfolioService _target;

        public static Func<object> TargetFactory;

        public ManualProxy()
        {
            _target = (IPortfolioService)TargetFactory();
        }

     
        public Task<Portfolio> Get(Guid traderId, int portfolioId)
        {
            return _target.Get(traderId,portfolioId);
        }

        public Task<List<Portfolio>> GetAll(Guid traderId)
        {
            return _target.GetAll(traderId);
        }
    }
```

This is the ManualProxy class.

[image]

The SVC file needs to be changed as above picture.